# In RStudio gwidgets2 with Rgtk2 and ggraphics, plot has a pseudo-rubber-band box?

Tags: r, plot, gwidgets, rubber-band

I want to draw a rubber-band box in a plot in a frame using `gwidgets2`. Unlike a plot in RStudio, a plot in a frame using `gwidgets2` draws a rubber-band box unbidden.  Sometimes it disappears, and sometimes it stays drawn, depending on the direction the mouse is moving at mouse-up.  What is causing this, and can I access or suppress this forbidden fruit?  I have not found it documented.

If not, is my best option to use `locator()`, or `getGraphicsEvent()`, or something else?

Here is code to show it.  Increment with the spin button to show the plot, then rubber-band it.

```
library(gWidgets2)
library(gWidgets2RGtk2)
options(guiToolkit="RGtk2")
library("cairoDevice")

MyPlot <- function()
{
  updateMyPlot <- function(h,...)
  {
    plot( 1:svalue(N), type="l")
  }

  BigGroup <- ggroup( container = TopWin )
  group <- ggroup( horizontal = FALSE, container = BigGroup )

  tmp <- gframe("N", container=group, expand=TRUE)
  N <- gspinbutton(from=1, to=10, container=tmp, handler = updateMyPlot)

  add( BigGroup, ggraphics() )
}

TopWin <<- gwindow("MAIN")

MyPlot()
```

Comment: It is turned on by default. I think this might turn it off: 1) name your ggraphics object (`nm <- ggraphic(cont=BigGroup`), 2) try calling `nm$widget$SetEvents(GdkEventMask["gdk-exposure-mask"])`

Comment: _Error in x[[value]] : subscript out of bounds_

Comment: Can't guess the cause here. Does nm$widget$setEvents error?

Comment: `nm <- ggraphics( cont = BigGroup )
  nm$widget$SetEvents #(GdkEventMask["gdk-exposure-mask"])

  add( BigGroup, nm )`

Comment: _(rsession.exe:13548): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_box_pack: assertion `child->parent == NULL' failed_   ... I am well out of my depth here.

Comment: Don't do the add call. This is already done in the first command via the CONT argument.